# How to take datas from apple time capsule

Tags: mac, time-capsule

I have an Apple Time Capsule which takes backup of several Mac machines in my company.
One of the Macs crashed and have been handed over to a service center.

I need to take the backup data of the crashed machine from Time Capsule. If I try to access Time Capsule from my Mac,it shows only back-up data from my own Mac.

How can I access back-up data from a different Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Try the **Browse Other Backup Disks**-Option via pressing the **Alt**-Key and clicking the TimeMachine-Icon in the Menubar as stated in the [TimeMachine-FAQ](http://pondini.org/TM/17.html).